# The value of "offset" is out of range. It must be >= 0 && <= 17825792

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, bson

```
    You have triggered an unhandledRejection, you may have forgotten to catch a Promise rejection:
 RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "offset" is out of range. It must be >= 0 && <= 17825792. Received 17825796
     at Buffer.write (buffer.js:1019:5)
     at serializeObjectId (/home/ubuntu/workspace/assurance-api/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:274:14)
     at serializeInto (/home/ubuntu/workspace/assurance-api/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:935:17)
     at serializeObject (/home/ubuntu/workspace/assurance-api/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:347:18)
     at serializeInto (/home/ubuntu/workspace/assurance-api/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:727:17)
     at serializeObject (/home/ubuntu/workspace/assurance-api/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:347:18)
     at serializeInto (/home/ubuntu/workspace/assurance-api/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:941:17)
     at BSON.serialize (/home/ubuntu/workspace/assurance-api/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/bson.js:64:28)
     at Msg.serializeBson (/home/ubuntu/workspace/assurance-api/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/msg.js:126:22)
     at Msg.makeDocumentSegment (/home/ubuntu/workspace/assurance-api/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/msg.js:118:33)
     at Msg.toBin (/home/ubuntu/workspace/assurance-api/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/msg.js:104:25)
     at MessageStream.writeCommand (/home/ubuntu/workspace/assurance-api/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:55:28)
     at Connection.write (/home/ubuntu/workspace/assurance-api/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:361:26)
     at _command (/home/ubuntu/workspace/assurance-api/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/wireprotocol/command.js:128:10)
     at command (/home/ubuntu/workspace/assurance-api/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/wireprotocol/command.js:28:5)
     at writeCommand (/home/ubuntu/workspace/assurance-api/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/wireprotocol/write_command.js:47:3)
```

i've been sending an axios.post with a payload of data and files to my express back-end , i catch the files in form of base64 and pop the front  letters which contain "data/png base64;"
when i try to create a new instance with the base64 data i get the following error when trying to save the document to mongodb, using mongoose, i looked this error up in vain, is the files too large?

Comment: hi, did you solve this?

Comment: hey, late response here, yes i did turns out my file was too big to be stored as a mongodb file, use something else rather than storing the buffer directly to the database

Comment: @Cocuba For help [https://stackoverflow.com/a/62176290/8987128](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62176290/8987128)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Your MongoDB query is too large. This happens when your search or update query exceeds 17.825.792 bytes.**

---

For those having the same issue. I have some extra information, after some testing I concluded the following things:

When you make a MongoDB insert request that changes an object so it becomes larger than the maximum allowed size (16mb) you will get the following error:

```
MongoError: BSONObj size: 20971588 (0x1400044) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: _id: ObjectId('60a277f50a5f8b012a761672')
    at Function.create ...
    {
  driver: true,
  index: 0,
  code: 10334
}
```

When you do a MongoDB **query** that is too large (like in the question). You will be presented with the following error:

```
RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "offset" is out of range. It must be >= 0 && <= 17825792. Received 17825794
    at validateOffset (buffer.js:104:3)
    at Buffer.write (buffer.js:1055:5)
    ... {
  code: 'ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE'
}
```

This is important because if you do for example an upsert that inserts or updates 10mb of data your query surpasses the max ~17mb of a query. (not entirely sure this was intended by the developers)

Lastly when you do an insert that **does not** exceed the maximum query size, but **does** exceed the maximum BSON document size you will be presented with this error:

```
MongoError: object to insert too large. size in bytes: 16777272, max size: 16777216
    at Function.create ...
     {
  driver: true,
  index: 0,
  code: 2
}
```

This was tested with:

- Node v14.16.0
- MongoDB node module v3.6.4

I hope this helps anyone who landed on this question.

Answer (score 1):

This may be of some help to others that run into the same issue as I.

Getting that error when trying to insert a larger-than-allowable document (16mb) makes perfect sense. But in my case I got the error when running a `find` query. The error I got was pretty much identical to the OP's:

```
RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "offset" is out of range. It must be >= 0 && <= 17825792. Received 17825801
    at Buffer.write (buffer.js:1052:5)
...
...
```

But what throws that error in my case is:

```
LeadDeliveryLog.find(query)
    .populate('lead', '-_id fname lname email phone city state zip ip')
    .lean()
    .then(leads => {
        console.log('Done', leads.length);
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.log('---------------ERROR--------------');
        console.log(e);
    })
```

*Note that I am using mongoose as a driver.* The above command is supposed to return about 1.3 mil records.

The way I solved it is by simply rewriting the find as an aggregation like so:

```
                    .aggregate([
                        {$match: query},
                        {
                            $lookup: {
                                'from': 'leads',
                                'localField': 'lead_id',
                                'foreignField': '_id',
                                'as': 'lead'
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "$project": {...}
                        }
                    ])
```

This allows me to retrieve those large amount of documents without any issues.