# Why my code is not able to save image details?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, multer

I am trying to implement a module where logged in users will upload property details and we can access those detail later on

```
// Configuring multer library
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

// new document
const doc = new propertyModel({
    _id: isVerified.userId,
    name: name,
    location: location,
    description: description,
    price: price,
    area: area,
    bedroom: bedroom,
    bathroom: bathroom,
    owner: owner,
    type: type,
    city: city,
    images: images,
    videos: videos
});
// save document
await doc.save();
```

error log :-

````
RangeError: offset is out of bounds
    at Buffer.set (<anonymous>)
    at serializeBuffer (C:\Users\siddharth singh\Documents\myalldetails\working\v6\backend\node_modules\bson\lib\parser\serializer.js:255:12)
    at serializeInto (C:\Users\siddharth singh\Documents\myalldetails\working\v6\backend\node_modules\bson\lib\parser\serializer.js:807:25)
    at serializeObject (C:\Users\siddharth singh\Documents\myalldetails\working\v6\backend\node_modules\bson\lib\parser\serializer.js:282:20)
    at serializeInto (C:\Users\siddharth singh\Documents\myalldetails\working\v6\backend\node_modules\bson\lib\parser\serializer.js:607:25)
    at serializeObject (C:\Users\siddharth singh\Documents\myalldetails\working\v6\backend\node_modules\bson\lib\parser\serializer.js:282:20)
    at serializeInto (C:\Users\siddharth singh\Documents\myalldetails\working\v6\backend\node_modules\bson\lib\parser\serializer.js:813:25)
    at serializeObject (C:\Users\siddharth singh\Documents\myalldetails\working\v6\backend\node_modules\bson\lib\parser\serializer.js:282:20)
    at serializeInto (C:\Users\siddharth singh\Documents\myalldetails\working\v6\backend\node_modules\bson\lib\parser\serializer.js:607:25)
    at serializeObject (C:\Users\siddharth singh\Documents\myalldetails\working\v6\backend\node_modules\bson\lib\parser\serializer.js:282:20) ```
````

Comment: please paster the error log as text

Comment: added text please have a look

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60996826/the-value-of-offset-is-out-of-range-it-must-be-0-17825792 try this